# How should I wash the potatoes before baking them?

Tags: baking, potatoes

I bake Russet potatoes. I just washed them a little with cold water and then place them in a  baking pan after I put foil on the bottom of the pan. I do not peel them. Is this a good method or should I wait until they dry?

Comment: What do you mean by " then added them on the foil in the oven."?

Comment: @TFD I edited it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For baking potatoes

- Don't just wash them, scrub them.  Otherwise you're eating dirt.  No, that's not a joke.  Potatoes grow in dirt, and are usually sold coated with dirt.  Yes, really.
- Either salt them and wrap them in tin-foil, or simply bake them on a 
  bed of salt.  Dessication of the skin is important.
- You'll probably      want to bake them longer and higher than most
  recipes say.  I find       425F for 1 1/2 hours is optimal (and 2
  hours is fine).  That results in skin which is dry, crispy, and slightly caramelized, while this inside still is fluffy (albeit, according to some, overcooked).

Comment: Another way to get crispy skins is to rub a tiny bit of oil around the surface.

Comment: What's wrong with eating dirt if you don't mind the taste or texture? Plus, isn't eating a bit of dirt here & there actually healthy for you? Why do I need to wash them at all? Isn't just the heat of the oven enough to sanitize them? Not washing them saves time & effort.

Comment: If the sweet potatoes are grown organically then the dirt is probably good for you.  For example, dirt contains vitamin B12 due to all the bacteria living there.

Answer (score 3):

You can just bake them on an oven rack or tray, Nothing special required

Drying them wont make much difference after an hour or so in the oven